# squares of integers, and multiples of 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Prove that for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ there exists $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that either $n^2=4k$ for $n^2 = 4k + 1$.

A hint given was: What are the possible remainders for n after dividing by 4? Break into the cases where you have each remainder.

Comment: Can you answer the question in the hint?

Comment: I think the answer to the title of this problem is yes.

Comment: @Tunococ, sorry, I edited the title so your comment no longer applies.

Answer (score 2):

Try to consider two different cases:

- If $n=2k$ when $n$ is even, so $n=4k^2=4k', k,k'\in\mathbb Z$
- If $n=2k+1$ when $n$ is odd, so $n^2=4k'+1, k'\in\mathbb Z$

Comment: Nice, Babak...+

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

> $k \equiv \pm 1$ or $2(\mod 4) \implies k^2 \equiv 1$ or $0(\mod 4)$

Proof:

When $k \in \text{odd}$, $k=2n+1 \implies k^2=4n^2+4n+1 =4n(n+1)+1$

When $k \in \text{even}, k=2n \implies k^2=4n^2$